# Javascript - document.createDocumentFragment() - referencing a element by ID

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it possible to refer to a element by its ID while it is inside of a documentFragment before it is appended to the document?

For example:

```
var docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var newElem = document.createElement('div');
docFragment.appendChild(newElem);
var newAttrib = document.createAttribute('id');
newAttrib.value = 'myid';
newElem.setAttributeNode(newAttrib);
var newElem2 = document.createElement('span');
docFragment.firstChild.appendChild(newElem2);
var newAttrib = document.createAttribute('id');
newAttrib.value = 'myid2';
newElem2.setAttributeNode(newAttrib);
```

For some examples, Ive tried this,

`alert(docFragment.getElementById('myid').id)` <----- but this does not work

`alert(docFragment.document.getElementById('myid').id)` <----- but this does not work

I know this works:

`alert(docFragment.firstChild.id)` <----- this does work, but I was wondering if it is possible to reference it the other ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[No, it is not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementByID):

> Simply creating an element and assigning an ID will not make the element accessible by `getElementById`. Instead one needs to insert the element first into the document tree with `insertBefore` or a similar method, probably into a hidden div.

And besides that, a `DocumentFragment` only implements methods of the [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node) interface and `getElementById` is not part of that.

There are no other ways to get an element by ID.

Comment: Thanks alot, that was what I was thinking just wanted to be sure